# How to get a data frame AFTER one matching a given condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have data frame df below

```
> df <- data.frame(value=c(1001, 1002, 1001, 1006, 1003, 1001, 1005))
> df
  value
1  1001
2  1002
3  1001
4  1006
5  1003
6  1001
7  1005
```

And I want to perform some operation (say mean()) on all rows that immediately follow rows where value = 1001

My instinct was

```
 mean(df$value[(df$value==1001) +1])
```

But this did not work, and I'm not even sure how to describe what I'm trying to do well enough to Google it. I'm sure the solution is stupid simple. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Did you just mean `mean(df$value[which(df$value==1001) +1])` ?

Comment: What is your expected output ? Is it going to be 3 values (1002, 1004.5, 1005) ?

Comment: In other words, are you trying to get the mean of each group of values between the 1001 values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! Missing `which`, and in case the last row has value `1001` and you'd get `NA` for the next row (and also just in case there were `NA` elsewhere) you need `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
mean(df$value[which(df$value == 1001) + 1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: One place you may have an issue is if there are consecutive 1001 values.